# R new column (variable) that rowSums across lists with NULL values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
UID<-c(rep(1:25, 2), rep(26:50, 2))
Group<-c(rep(5, 25), rep(20, 25), rep(-18, 25), rep(-80, 25))
Value<-sample(100:5000, 100, replace=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(UID, Group, Value)
```

But I need the values separated into new rows so I run this:

```
df<-pivot_wider(df, names_from = Group, 
                    values_from = Value, 
                    values_fill = list(Value = 0))
```

Which introduces `NULL` into the dataset. Sorry, could not figure out a way to get an example dataset with `NULL` values. Note: this is now a `tbl_df`  `tbl`  `data.frame`

These aren't great variable names so I run this:

```
colnames(df)[which(names(df) == "20")] <- "pos20"
colnames(df)[which(names(df) == "5")] <- "pos5"
colnames(df)[which(names(df) == "-18")] <- "neg18"
colnames(df)[which(names(df) == "-80")] <- "neg80"
```

What I want to be able to do is create a new column (variable) that `rowSums` across columns. So I run this:

```
df<-df%>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(rowTot = rowSums(.[2:5]))
```

Which of course works on the example dataset but not on the one with `NULL` values. I have tried converting `NULL` to `NA` using `df[df== "NULL"] <- NA` but the values do not change. I have tried converting the lists to numeric using `as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[[2]])))` but I get an error telling me I have unequal number of rows, which I guess would be expected.

I realize there might be a better process to get my desired end result, so any suggestions to any of this is most appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a link to the actual dataset which will introduce `Null` values after using `pivot_wider`. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGh-Vjmpmpo8_sFAtGedxzfCiTpYnKZ3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to answer with confidence without an actual reproducible example where the error occurs but I am going to take a guess.

I think your `pivot_wider` steps produces list columns (meaning some values are vectors) and that is why you are getting `NULL` values. Create a unique row for each `Group` and then use `pivot_wider`. Also `rowSums` has `na.rm` parameter so you don't need `replace`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(temp) %>%   
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = temp, values_from = numseeds) %>%
  mutate(rowTot = rowSums(.[3:6], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Please change the column numbers according to your data in `rowSums` if needed.

Comment: This would be a very eloquent solution that does work on my real data, except that I need only a single line per UID.

Comment: Okay and what do you want to do of `Group` and `Value` column? Do you want `sum`/`mean` of them for each `UID`?

Comment: For a single UID I would like the value in each group plus the sum of values from every group.

Comment: Does this work? `df %>% group_by(UID, Group) %>%  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Value, values_fill = 0)`

Comment: On the example dataset it does not make the sum column. On the real data it is for some reason telling me the values column does not exist (I've triple checked that it does exist and is spelled correctly).

Comment: Hmmm...I am not sure then what is happening without a proper example.

Comment: I have edited the question so as to provide a link to the actual dataset which will introduce NULL values after using pivot_wider. Thank you so much for helping me with this.

Comment: @Dustin For your data I think you need `df1 <- df %>% group_by(temp) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = temp, values_from = numseeds)`. Can you check if that works for you?

Comment: Yes, this works perfect!!! Thank you! Now I just need a final column that is the sum of all temps. I tried mutate rowSums, but I get a column with only NAs.

Comment: You can add `na.rm = TRUE` in `rowSums`. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes of course, forgive my memory for not remembering na.rm. This now works perfectly! I am extremely grateful for you aid! I smell coffee!